# A Brauer group of a double covering of a "well-understood" variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, brauer-groups

Let $k$ be a field (it is possible to assume that $k = \mathbb{Q}$ or $= \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$) and $X, Y$ nice varieties over $k$.
Let $f \colon Y \to X$ be a finite flat surjective morphism of degree $2$.

If we understand the structure of $\operatorname{Br} X$ (and of other $H^i(X, \mathbb{G}_m)$)), then what can we say about $\operatorname{Br} Y$?

For example, if $X$ is a surface with $\operatorname{Br} X = \operatorname{Br} \mathbb{Q}$, and if $f$ is etale, then what is $\operatorname{Br} Y / \operatorname{Br} \mathbb{Q}$?

What is understood about this situation beyond Alexei N. Skorobogatov's "Cohomology and the Brauer group of double covers" [[ZBMath1372.14011]](https://zbmath.org/1372.14011),  [[MR3616013]](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=3616013)?
The case of etale covering seems to be easier than this paper for me, and so I am wondering if there is such a paper.